# copying cn1lib in lib directory does not work

Tags: codenameone

I copied some .cn1lib files into my lib directory and refreshed it. But i'm not able to use these libraries.I am using Eclipse ide. What should i do ?
Is it related to codename one plugin for eclipse or specific to ide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you downloaded a valid file, the cn1lib should be a zip file. Its easy to verify it by copying it to the side, renaming it to .zip and checking that you can open it.

Also make sure you pressed the `Refresh Libs` option in the menu and not something else.